# Differential equation with non-constant trigonometric coefficient

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find general solution of the following:-
$$ (\sin^2x)y'' -(2\sin x \cos x)y' +(\cos^2x +1)y= \sin^3x. $$
I know how to solve if the leading coefficient is $x^2$ (in that we substitute $x = e^z,$ but I'm not able to do for this. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly $y=\sin x$ is a solution to the corresponding homogeneous equation. Let $y=z\sin x$ and then one has
$$ z''\sin^3 x=\sin^3x $$
or 
$$ z''=1. $$
So $z=\frac12 x^2+C_1x+C_2$. So the equation has the general solution
$$ y=\sin x(\frac12 x^2+C_1x+C_2). $$

Answer (score 1):

Solving the homogeneous equation:
$$(\sin^2x)y'' -(2\sin x \cos x)y' +(\cos^2x +1)y= 0$$
Substitute $v=\dfrac {y'}{y}$
$$(\sin^2x)(v'+v^2) -(2\sin x \cos x)v +(\cos^2x +1)= 0$$
$$(\sin (x) v -\cos (x))^2 +v'\sin^2 (x)  +1= 0$$
$$( v -\cot (x))^2 + v' + \frac  1 {\sin^2 (x)}= 0$$
$$w^2+w'=0$$
$$\left ( \frac 1 w \right )'=1$$
Where $w=\dfrac {y'}{y} -\cot (x)$.
$$\dfrac {y'}{y} -\cot (x)=\dfrac 1 {x+C}$$
$$(\ln y )'=\cot (x)+\dfrac 1 {x+C}$$
Integrate.
$$\boxed {y(x)=c_1\sin(x)+c_2x\sin(x)}$$